# Jquery tools overlay redirect page on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an age confirmation box that pops up on page load

If the user clicks yes, then the overlay should just close, but if the user clicks no I would like to close the overlay and redirect the user to another page.

This is the code I have

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#confirmage").overlay({

    // custom top position
    top: 260,
    mask: {
    color: '#fff',
    loadSpeed: 200,
    opacity: 0.9
    },

    closeOnClick: false,
    api: true,
    load: true

    });
});
$('.link-no').click(function () {
    $("#confirmage").overlay().close();
    window.location.href = 'insert_page_here';
});
```

And on the .html I have this

```
<div id="confirmage">
  <div>
    <h2>Are you older than 18 years old?</h2>
    <p>
      <button class="close">Yes</button>
      <button class="link-no close">No</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Right now, when the user clicks No the overlay just closes but it doesnt redirect the user to the page.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Can you please update your code to add the #confirmage div HTML code?

Comment: why you need to close the overlay when you are redirecting it after just click

Comment: I added the rest of the HTML code. And well it can just redirect, it is not necessary to close when the user clicks no

Comment: then remove that layout closing statement, and try, does that work ?? just a query, is that Layout iframe ??

Comment: I tried removing that, and without it nothing happens. And I believe that is not an iframe

Comment: Seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/mLyv4

Comment: BTW, "older than 18 years old" is redundant. :-)

Comment: Remove your no button "close" class `<button class="link-no">No</button>` instead of `<button class="link-no **close**">No</button>`

Comment: Ooops! Am I contributing in any adult-related materials sites? Shame of me!

Comment: HAhaha It is adult-related, but it is not what you're thinking. It's a site for an alcoholic beverage. And in Brazil, the legal age for drinking is 18 years old

Comment: @isherwood thanks. I will fix that =] I thought I typo'd something, but I just copy pasted from my source code

Comment: I just reviewed the code and on my server it closes the overlay but doesn't redirect =/ and I have both <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script> loaded in the <head>